# Simple yet lost: Embeding Javascript into HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All I want to do is use this code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atNva/196)
for an un-clickable button but I cant seem to embed the JS the way that i'm used to. I feel my problem is telling it what the img is. this is what i have.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
    $('#img').mouseover(function() {
        var dWidth = $(document).width() - 100, // 100 = image width
            dHeight = $(document).height() - 100, // 100 = image height
            nextX = Math.floor(Math.random() * dWidth),
            nextY = Math.floor(Math.random() * dHeight);
        $(this).animate({ left: nextX + 'px', top: nextY + 'px' });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <p>Yada yada yada.<p>
    </div>
        <img src="poop.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Grey Square" id="img" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: is this not java? I thoguht it was java... As it stands Im only literate in HTML and CSS.

Comment: You tagged it as both javascript and java — but Java and Javascript are almost completely unrelated.

Comment: @newbyJP *"Java is to JavaScript such as Car is to Carpet"* ;)

Comment: my apologize, I had no idea there was a different, but that is a great simile explanation.

Comment: There are some great jQuery video tutorials over on [TheNewBoston](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32). You may also wish to watch additional jQuery videos on the presenter's own website [phpAcademy.org](http://phpacademy.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a few closing brackets and the part that loads jQuery itself:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#img').mouseover(function() {
        var dWidth = $(document).width() - 100, // 100 = image width
            dHeight = $(document).height() - 100, // 100 = image height
            nextX = Math.floor(Math.random() * dWidth),
            nextY = Math.floor(Math.random() * dHeight);
        $(this).animate({ left: nextX + 'px', top: nextY + 'px' });
    });   /// HERE
});   /// AND HERE
</script>
```

I suggest before learning jQuery, you should learn Javascript — surprisingly, and contrary to popular belief, those two are actually *not* the same thing!

Also, you need to pay attention to the error console of the browser; if you did, you'd have noticed the syntax error caused by the missing closing brackets.

Comment: Your right i did remove those on accident in other failed attempts, but this did not make my image move.

Comment: sorry; I actually also missed one bracket — edited; try again.

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined calc.html:23
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: OK, I realized you weren't even loading jQuery itself to begin with... see my updated answer.

Comment: I know i'm not suposed to say thanks based on the thing but... thanks a bunch you guys were a bunch of life savers.

Comment: @newbyJP: why did you just accept this answer and then the other answer? you can only accept one answer and it should be the best one.

Comment: Hobo and you both came to the same solution at about the same time, i didn't realize they couldnt both be selected.

Comment: Yeah, but there were several issues in your code; my answer pointed out all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a JavaScript library called jQuery. This is a resource you need to include in your page. before `</body>`, write:
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`
[Explore this](http://www.jquery.com) for more info.

Comment: i had high hopes for this one, but it still sits stagnently on the page. :{

Comment: I think the point of the `jQuery(...)` call is exactly to have the code executed *after* the page has loaded.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed that because I'm not used to that signature. Anyway, @newby, did you include jQuery in your code?

Comment: @climbinghobo I posted the entirety of my page without all the added visible text. i'm not sure what you mean by "did i included..." but my gut says very strongly "i think??"

Comment: You're using a JavaScript library called jQuery. This is a resource you need to include in your page. before `</body>`, write:
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`
[Explore this](http://jquery.com/) for more info.

Comment: Ok I'll update the answer... I would also suggest that you learn vanilla JavaScript basics before using jQuery, and definitely learn what jQuery is before using it :)